# First accordion tab open by using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to make first accordion tab open by using JavaScript, NOT CSS. here is my JavaScript code and [demo is here](https://jsfiddle.net/ofkhkv2g/). thanks in advance. :))

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    function close_accordion_section() {
        jQuery('.accordion .accordion-section-title').removeClass('active');
        jQuery('.accordion .accordion-section-content').slideUp(300).removeClass('open');
    }

    jQuery('.accordion-section-title').click(function(e) {
        // Grab current anchor value
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

        if(jQuery(e.target).is('.active')) {
            close_accordion_section();
        }else {
            close_accordion_section();

            // Add active class to section title
            jQuery(this).addClass('active');
            // Open up the hidden content panel
            jQuery('.accordion ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(300).addClass('open'); 
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try as below:

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({ active: 0 });
```

It is better way as per [Jquery Document](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active)

Answer (score 0):

You could fake a click on the header like this:

```
$('.accordion-section-title').first().click();
```